# What scope does an "at" sigil (@) give within Ruby functions?

Tags: ruby, scope, sigils

It's been a while since I last did Ruby programming -- looking at somebody else's code, I see the `@` sigil in a function (*not* a method -- external to any class definition), which I understood to be scoped to instance members.

Is the module the implied `self` in functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a top-level function (still a method really), you're in a slightly strange place: a global "main" space (see the prompt when you run `irb`, or try looking at `self` inside such a function), but also these functions are defined as private methods inside the `Object` class.

```
$ cat foo
def foo
  p self
  p self.class
  puts 'foo'
end

foo
Object.foo

$ ruby foo
main
Object
foo
foo:8: private method `foo' called for Object:Class (NoMethodError)
$
```

You can sneak around this by explicitly declaring these methods `public`, but I'm not sure I like this! Curiously, if you define a top-level method inside `irb`, then you can call it via the class method `Object#foo` without declaring it public.

So this is a kind of an "implied main namespace hacked onto `Object` (but shhh don't tell anyone)". `@foo` defined inside a top-level function is available inside Object, as a plain old attribute. Sort of. If your top-level method set `@foo` and you call it without scoping then it is declared in the eigen-like `main` namespace, but if you call the class method via `Object` then `@foo` appears in the space of `Object`.

Another example:

```
public
def set_foo
  @foo = 'foo'
end

def get_foo
  @foo
end

def Object.get_foo_again
  @foo
end

set_foo
p get_foo
p Object.get_foo_again

Object.set_foo
p Object.get_foo_again
```

gives

```
"foo"  # @foo set in main
nil    # @foo nil in Object  
"foo"  # @foo in Object
```

The converse also applies.

Answer (score 2):

The assumption that this is "a function, not a method" is wrong. All Ruby code occurs within the context of some object. The "global" context is an Object called `main` (try `ruby -e "puts self"` if you don't believe it). Methods defined in the top scope become instance methods of Object. This means that the method will be available *anywhere*, with `self` (and thus the context that instance variables belong to) depending on where the method is called

Comment: Okay, so is @ident within a  module-level function another way of saying $ident?

Comment: No, it sets the @ident instance variable of the module (remember, in Ruby, a Module is an Object too and can have its own ivars). "@ident = something" will set the @ident instance variable of whatever "self" is at the moment.

Comment: Okay, so globals are truly global (bound to the interpreter), not confined to the scope of any given module?

Comment: So is it common practice to use @ident in module-level functions to make module-scoped identifiers? I would think that it would be more straightforward to pre-declare them at the start of the module.

Answer (score 1):

I think it scopes it to a module.

Answer (score 1):

@ makes a variable an instance variable. It sounds like it's not a part of an explicitly declared class, so it's going to available within the main object as Chuck pointed out. It's easier illustrated by example:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> @var = 1
=> 1
irb(main):002:0> class New
irb(main):003:1>   def test
irb(main):004:2>     puts @var
irb(main):005:2>   end
irb(main):006:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):007:0> test = New.new
=> #<New:0xb7ccbc14>
irb(main):008:0> test.test
nil
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> def test2
irb(main):010:1>   puts @var
irb(main):011:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):012:0> test2
1
=> nil
```